# Access Denied You don't have permission to access Stubhub api call

Tags: php, laravel

I am experiencing difficulty accessing a  Stubhub API curl call on AWS ubuntu server. When I try accessing it with my local computer I have no problem. But on server when I call API, I got:

> Access Denied You don't have permission to access "http://www.stubhub.com/" on this server. Reference #18.b5b31bb8.1441799024.21db8e87

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Contact StubHub support.

Comment: Thanks, but can you guess why such error accrued. so I can check that reasons before proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server's ip address has been blacklisted (banned) from Stubhub's api. Unfortunately you'll have to contact their support to get it unblocked (or request a new elastic IP from AWS).